# What is the correct way to build an output string by iterating over several elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a list of labels, e.g., `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`, and a list of suffixes, e.g., `['left', 'right']`, and I would like to create a pair of strings which combine the two lists systematically, e.g., `lstr = 'Aleft, Bleft, Cleft, Dleft, '` and `rstr = 'Aright, Bright, Cright, Dright, '`.  I tried to write a set of nested for loops in order to do this, like so:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
suffix = ['left', 'right']

# This is what I actually want to do, and it works exactly as desired inside
# of the for loop, but I can't pass the result back outside of the for loop
lstr, rstr = '', ''
for lr, s in zip([lstr, rstr], suffix):
    for lbl in labels:
        lr += lbl + s + ", "
    print(lr)

print(lstr)
print(rstr)

# Just for comparison, this is syntactically very similar to what I want to
# do, and it does work as desired
llist, rlist = [], []
for lr, s in zip([llist, rlist], suffix):
    for lbl in labels:
    lr.append(lbl + s)

print(llist)
print(rlist)
```

This code snippet yields the following 6-line result:

```
Aleft, Bleft, Cleft, Dleft, 
Aright, Bright, Cright, Dright, 


['Aleft', 'Bleft', 'Cleft', 'Dleft']
['Aright', 'Bright', 'Cright', 'Dright']
```

Essentially, the two strings that I want are indeed being constructed correctly inside of the first pair of nested for loops, resulting in the first two correct/desired lines which you can see at the beginning of the output.  However, the for loops fail to "pass the result back up" to the higher-level `lstr, rstr` variables on the outside of the for loops, with the result that the next two lines of output, produced by the `print(lstr)` and `print(rstr)` statements, are blank.

Just for comparison, the second pair of nested for loops are also a syntactically very similar construction to the first, except that instead of building a string, one builds a list.  Unlike the first example, this construction works as expected--the reference to the resulting list is passed back up above the for loops, and printing out the result leads to the final two lines in the output.

I suspect that the difference in behavior between these two nearly identical constructions is somehow related to the fact that Python objects technically are [neither pass by value nor pass by reference](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html).  However, I'm not quite sure what to actually do about it.

So, therefore, my question: what is the most succinct, correct and/or "Pythonic" way of restructuring the first pair of nested for loops, so that I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
suffixes = ['left', 'right']

result = (', '.join(label+suffix for label in labels) for suffix in suffixes)

for line in result:
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested list comprehension to make a list of lists for you. This is extensible in the sense that `labels` and `suffix` could have any dimensions.

```
>>> labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> suffix = ['left', 'right']
>>> [[''.join([i,j]) for i in labels] for j in suffix]
[['Aleft', 'Bleft', 'Cleft', 'Dleft'], ['Aright', 'Bright', 'Cright', 'Dright']]
```

After re-reading your post, it looks like you may have wanted two strings, concatenated by commas. If that is correct, you can modify the above to:

```
>>> [', '.join(''.join([i,j]) for i in labels) for j in suffix]
['Aleft, Bleft, Cleft, Dleft', 'Aright, Bright, Cright, Dright']
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable; strings aren't, so you reference to another object rather that modifying the object itself.

Consider this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = A
B.append(5)
```

Right now both B and A point to the same object, which is the list composed of the numbers 1 to 5.

But this:

```
S1 = "1, 2, 3, 4"
S2 = S1
S2 += ", 5"
```

By doing this you don't actually change the string, but rather create a new one, `"1, 2, 3, 4" + ", 5"`, and thus S2 points to a new object and not to the same object as S1, which is still pointing to `"1, 2, 3, 4"`.

More information:

[Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple strings at once, so if you know it'll just be `lstr` and `rstr` you can do the following with list comprehension:

```
lstr, rstr = [', '.join('{}{}'.format(i, j) for j in suffixes) for i in labels]
```

Note the placement of iteration; `for j in suffixes` is within the scope of the `''.join()` call but `for i in labels` is just in the list comprehension, which might at first seem intuitively backwards (or at least it 'feels' backwards to me, but it isn't).